# Is there a better way to keep a console app from returning besides using while?

Tags: c#, .net, timer, console-application

I have a small C# console application that runs some code then checks for a specific executable to complete.

The problem I had (I don't normally write console applications) is when I get to the code that checks for the termination of an executable, my Main() returns and the console application closes. The code which checks for the executable is running thru a Timer(). For the moment I've kept the Main alive by adding while(true) { } and that seems to be working except that it (obviously) eats up a ton of excess CPU time.

Is there a better way to keep the Main() function from returning?

```
    static Timer tmrCheck = new Timer();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Initialize();
        while (true) ; // If this line is removed, the application will close after
                       // the last line of Initialize() is run.
    }

    static void Initialize()
    {
        tmrCheck.Elapsed += tmrCheck_Elapsed;
        tmrCheck.Interval = 10000;
        tmrCheck.Enabled = true; // After this line, Initialize returns to Main()
    }

    static void tmrCheck_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Get a list of processes
        // Check to see if process has exited
        // If so, run *this* code then exit console application.
        // If not, keep timer running.
    }
```

Comment: Can you share your code? A tiny example of what you doing would be great.

Comment: Added code to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to wait until the launched process exits.
This could be written in your `Timer.Elapsed` event

```
Process[] p = Process.GetProcessesByName("yourprocessname");
if(p.Length > 0) 
{
    p[0].WaitForExit();
    Console.WriteLine("Finish");    
}
else
{ 
    // Do other things
}
```

**EDIT**
Looks that this could be tried. I am not sure about threading issues here so waiting for someone more expert that points to the weakness of this approach

```
static Timer tmrCheck = new Timer();
static bool waiting = false;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Initialize();
    Console.WriteLine("Press enter to stop the processing....");
    Console.ReadLine();
    tmrCheck.Stop();
}

static void Initialize()
{
    tmrCheck.Elapsed += (s, e) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Timer event");
        if(!waiting)
        {
            Process[] p = Process.GetProcessesByName("yourprocessname");
            if(p.Length > 0)
            {
                waiting = true;
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for exit");
                p[0].WaitForExit();
                Timer t = s as Timer;
                t.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("Press enter to end application");

            }
        }
        else
        {
            // other processing activities
        }
    };
    tmrCheck.Interval = 10000;
    tmrCheck.Enabled = true; 
}
```

Comment: Well, I thought about that, except that I'm not executing the executable from the console application. The executable is ran elsewhere. The console application (in the timer every 10000ms) gets a list of running processes then checks the list to see if a specific executable is running or not. If it's not, then it fires up more code before exiting. Also, the code that checks for the process isn't being run from the Main() function. It is running in it's own Timer.Elapsed event.

Comment: I understand better now. However, the code that checks for the process running or not should be able to get a list of processes active. I don't know but perhaps, having the process instance available allows to call WaitForExit

Comment: We use Process.GetProcesses();

I'm not sure how it will respond to WaitForExit() on a process we didn't create but you might be on to something. I didn't really think about instancing a process into the process object. I'll try that and see where it goes.

Comment: We were able to take a simplier approach and used your idea to instance a copy of the process object and the WaitForExit worked out.

After GetProcesses() we iterated thru the list until we found the process we were looking for then instanced the process to a new object and threw the WaitForExit() in the main(). We ran the remaining code after the process exited and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try: Thread.Sleep(1); in your while loop. Even sleeping one millisecond should save you a lot of CPU cycles.

Hope that helps

Comment: I am afraid that this may cause the computer to consider the application unresponsive and close. We were thinking of using Sleep (1000) but we want to try to stay away from code that might consider the process unresponsive. This is a last resort option for us.

Comment: I asked one of the other people on my team about this, they actually did try this last night. It causes the code on the timer to stop at each interval of sleep so that wouldn't work out too well.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use as others mentioned Thead.Sleep and rewrite your code like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   while (true) 
   {
        // Get a list of processes
        // Check to see if process has exited
        // If so, run *this* code then exit console application.
        // If not, keep timer running.
       Thread.Sleep(10000); // Wait 10s and retry your previous actions
   }
}
```

Another suggestion (i sometimes using for thread cancellation option)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   int timeout = 10;
   int timeoutCount = 10;
   while (true) 
   {
      //Here you can check cancellation flag

      if(timeout == timeoutCount)
      {
        timeoutCount = 0;
        // Get a list of processes
        // Check to see if process has exited
        // If so, run *this* code then exit console application.
        // If not, keep timer running.
      }
      Thread.Sleep(1000); // Wait 1s and retry your previous actions
      timeoutCount++;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var procs = Process.GetProcessesByName("LINQPad").ToList();

    if (procs.Any())
    {
        procs.ForEach(p => p.EnableRaisingEvents = true);
        procs.ForEach(p => p.Exited += OnExited);
        procs.ForEach(p => p.WaitForExit());
    }

    Console.WriteLine("All processes exited...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static void OnExited(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Process Has Exited");
}
```

You didn't mention if you're monitoring multiple processes or not, but you could just remove the .ForEach statements and do the same logic for a single process, if not.  Also, i'm not sure if Console.ReadKey() is what you had in mind for keeping the process from exiting...  Or if you only need to keep it from exiting until the process(es) have closed.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what version of the .Net framework you're using or if the application launches the process, but...  If you're using 4.0 or higher and the app does launch the process, then you can use a Task ([System.Threading.Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks(v=vs.110).aspx)) to launch the process and Task.Wait.

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
static Timer tmrCheck = new Timer();
Task doWork;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Initialize();
     /// do more work if required
    doWork.Wait();

}

static void Initialize()
{
    tmrCheck.Elapsed += tmrCheck_Elapsed;
    tmrCheck.Interval = 10000;
    tmrCheck.Enabled = true; // After this line, Initialize returns to Main()
   // Initialize() seems the place to do start up, but this code could move to where ever the proocess is started.
    doWork = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                startTheProcessHere();
            }
        );
}
```

Pluralsight has a good course: [Introduction to Async and Parallel Programming in .NET 4](http://pluralsight.com/courses/intro-async-parallel-dotnet4)